# Quickest way to copy a nearly empty array

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, copy

I have to optimize a really crappy c++ code. The guy who made it doesn't know how to code: It has memory stomps, indices are used starting from 1 instead of 0, spagetthi code, you name a bad practice and there it is.

So 40% of the time this algorithm is copying large arrays which are nearly empty. I'm trying to make minimal changes because that would probably mean changing thousands and thousands lines of code and any mistake would mean getting completely different results.

So instead of declaring this large, nearly empty arrays like this:
short HLLE[dimcl]; //define dimcl 600

I'm doing something like this

```
    ArrayTimes HLLE;
    
/////
// Stores the occupied positions in another array, when copying, instead of copying all, empty the occupied ones
// then fill with the other occupied ones
    class ArrayTimes
    {
    public:
        ArrayTimes(int numTasks);
        ArrayTimes(const ArrayTimes& _other);
        virtual ~ArrayTimes();
        inline short& operator[](int _index)
        {
            auto &result = (*m_times)[_index];
            if (result == 0) //if there was already a value doesn't count as occupied again
            {
                (*m_occupied)[m_numOccupied] = _index;
                ++m_numOccupied;
            }
            return result;
        }
    
        inline const short& operator[](int _index) const
        {
            return (*m_times)[_index];
        }
    
        inline ArrayTimes& operator= (const ArrayTimes &_other)
        {
            //vaciamos
            for (int i = 0; i < m_numOccupied; ++i)
            {
                auto occIndex = m_occupied->operator[](i);
                m_times->operator[](occIndex) = 0;
            }
    
            *m_occupied = *(_other.m_occupied);
            m_numOccupied = _other.m_numOccupied;
    
            for (int i = 0; i < _other.m_numOccupied; ++i)
            {
                auto occIndex = _other.m_occupied->operator[](i);
                m_times->operator[](occIndex) = _other.m_times->operator[](occIndex);
            }
            return *this;
        }

    ArrayTimes::ArrayTimes(int numTasks) :
        m_numOccupied(0)
    {
        m_occupied = new std::vector<int>();
        m_times = new std::vector<short>();
    
        m_times->resize(numTasks);
        m_occupied->resize(numTasks / 4);
    }
    
    ArrayTimes::ArrayTimes(const ArrayTimes& _other)
    {
        m_occupied = new std::vector<int>();
        m_times = new std::vector<short>();
    
    
        auto datosGlobales = DatosGlobalesProblema::getInstance();
        auto numTareas = datosGlobales->GetNumTareas() + 1;
    
        m_occupied = new std::vector<int>();
        m_times = new std::vector<short>();
    
        m_times->resize(numTareas);
        m_occupied->resize(numTareas / 4);
    
        operator=(_other);
    }
    
    ArrayTimes::~ArrayTimes()
    {
        delete m_times;
        delete m_occupied;
    }
    
    
    int ArrayTimes::Size() const
    {
        return m_occupied->size();
    }
```

I have tried several containers to store the occupied positions: list, set, unordered set, map. None of them is quicker than copying all the array positions.

I guess the right answer is finding another way to save that information without wasting memory in such arrays of memory, altough that means refactoring thousands of lines of code.

Comment: Why are you allocating vectors with `new`? That's just one of a few strange things I see in your code.

Comment: You use `std::vector` so you *don't* have to do manual allocations with `new`. If you want faster, get rid of that first.

Comment: I also think this code has numerous severe memory leaks, like in the `ArrayTimes` constructor things are allocated twice for no reason.

Comment: I want the vector to have their elements in the heap, that's why I'm declaring the vector with new. Am I right?

Thanks for noticing the leak, I worked until really late yesterday and I was too tired.

Comment: The vector's elements are always heap allocated no matter where the vector itself is allocated

Comment: You are confusing the vector with the vectors elements. The vectors elements are always on the heap (unless you write a custom allocator) but the vector itself maybe on the heap or the stack. It exactly the same as with a pointer. A pointer can be on the stack, but what it's pointing at can be on the heap.

Comment: I'm certainly no expert on optimization, but I think it's well known that CPUs work better with contiguous blocks of memory. So it wouldn't surprise me to learn that code that 'wastefully' copies large blocks of contiguous memory is faster than code which is copying smaller blocks of memory which are discrete.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying that

Comment: Me talking about crappy code and see what I did... I think because the algorithm runs out of stack memory and I thought it was because of that

Comment: OT: Member functions defined within a class definition are implicitly _inline_, so the `inline` specifier is superfluous for them.

Comment: I thought the inline thing depends on the compiler, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following code has this timings with 300 to 600 copy. You don't need to copy anything manually with `std::vector`.

I've changed the `=` operator but you have to go through one of the vectors to see what you have to copy.

Also you can have more `m_times` than indexes in `m_occupied` so you shouldn't count on occupied vector.

```
Size: 300, 75
Element: 90

real    0m0,002s
user    0m0,002s
sys 0m0,000s
```

```
class ArrayTimes
{
    std::vector<int> m_occupied;
    std::vector<short> m_times;
    int m_numOccupied;
    
public:
    
    ArrayTimes(int numTasks) :
        m_numOccupied(0)
    {
        m_times.resize(numTasks);
        m_occupied.resize(numTasks / 4);
    }
    
    ArrayTimes(const ArrayTimes& _other)
    {
        auto numTareas = 600;

        m_times.resize(numTareas);
        m_occupied.resize(numTareas / 4);
    
        operator=(_other);
    }
    
    ~ArrayTimes()
    {
    }
    
    inline short& operator[](int _index)
    {
        auto &result = m_times[_index];
        if (result == 0) //if there was already a value doesn't count as occupied again
        {
            m_occupied[m_numOccupied] = _index;
            ++m_numOccupied;
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    inline const short& operator[](int _index) const
    {
        return m_times[_index];
    }
    
    inline ArrayTimes& operator= (const ArrayTimes &_other)
    {
        m_times.reserve (_other.m_times.size());
        for (auto e : _other.m_occupied) {
            m_times[e] = _other.m_times[e];
        }
        m_numOccupied = _other.m_numOccupied;
        return *this;
    }
    
    int OSize() const
    {
        return m_times.size();
    }

    int Size() const
    {
        return m_occupied.size();
    }
    
};

int main ()
{
    ArrayTimes a1(600);
    ArrayTimes a2(300);

    a2[3] = 9;

    a1 = a2;

    std::cout << "Size: " << a1.OSize() << ", " << a1.Size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Element: " << a1[3] << std::endl; // copied value from a2
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the point is avoid copying the whole vector.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to shrink the array to few elements, so there is no need of this tricky class.
Thanks for pointing out my mistakes, at least I learned something from this experience